# How to get Display Name of Contact by User ID in Applozic?

Tags: java, android, api, android-contacts, applozic

I am using Digits by Twitter alongside **[Applozic](https://www.applozic.com/)** SDK. I am creating a custom contact list, by using Find Friends provided by Digits, and then using their friends' IDs to get their display name from **Applozic**.

> This my code:

```
Log.e("Friend ID", user.idStr);
AppContactService appContactService = new AppContactService(context);
Contact contact = appContactService.getContactById(user.idStr);
Log.e("Friend Display Name", contact.getDisplayName());
```

> This is my logcat output:

```
E/Friend ID: 753958303214870528
E/Friend Display Name: 753958303214870528
E/Friend ID: 751769088456790016
E/Friend Display Name: 751769088456790016
```

As you can see, even **getDisplayName()** returns **UserID**. This is my **Applozic** Dashboard

[image].

Is there anything I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to make server call and get the User details from server. The above method which your are using it will only check from local data base

You can user this method to get the details from server

```
 Set<String> userIds = new HashSet<>();
             userIds.add("user1");
             userIds.add("user2");
             userIds.add("user3");

   UserService.getInstance(context).processUserDetails(userIds); //server call

   AppContactService appContactService = new AppContactService(context);
   Contact contact = appContactService.getContactById("user1");
            if(contact != null){
               Log.e("Friend Display Name", contact.getDisplayName());
              }
```